# SSL Certificate Site Issue - Google Analytics?

Tags: ssl, google-analytics, ssl-certificate, insecure-connection

I have a website which has an SSL certificate installed. If I navigate to the site via https://www.[MY-SITE].com then it flashes up in Chrome for a second with a green https:// indication. Then it greys out and shows the message that the site is loading up insecure content.

Some of the links on the site are still the old http:// versions but it isn't actually loading anything from the files it is linking to. One thing I thought of was that I don't have access to change the Google Analytics code to the https:// so it is still on the http:// in the admin settings on Google. Would this be the issue?

Thanks,

Jack

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may occur mistakes I think. I just search out some post from web regarding your queries. 
please read this link :

http://blogoscoped.com/archive/2007-12-13-n83.html

http://code.google.com/p/r-google-analytics/issues/detail?id=1

I hope it will be helpful for you.

Comment: Some really useful info, I will check out and have a test but I think it is what I needed! Thanks a lot fella!